# Is it possible to convert an xlrd object to a win32com object

Tags: django, win32com, xlrd

```
from win32com import client
import xlrd
```

I upload a excel file from a view (via a form) and thanks to xlrd, I am able to get the excel file object

```
if request. Method == 'POST':
    my_xlsx = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=request. FILES['my_excel_document'].read(), on_demand=True)
```

I would like to transform this xlrd object (xlrd.book.Book) to a win32com object without saving it.

```
app = client. Dispatch("Excel.Application")
sheets = app.Worbooks.Open(???)
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: I suspect this is not possible. Although both work with the XLS format, xlrd and Microsoft Excel are two distinct pieces of software with their own internal data representations, so I wouldn't expect to be able to convert one to the other. Maybe you can write the workbook to a temporary file and let Excel open that? Or since you have Excel available, maybe you don't need xlrd?